# Regarding use of "functions" in C

Tags: c, function, programming-languages

I am a beginner in programming and i have been stuck on the following issue for a couple of days now.

I am rewriting [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4185393/TP2_C.c) piece of code i created, by using '**functions**' only. Note that in the execution of the original, we have the average coffee consumption of the programmers = **1.25**. However, by using function [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4185393/Scratch.c) i get a different number **0.63**.

I am trying to figure out where the mistake is, but i am stuck. ***Can someone explain me where my mistake is, and maybe give me some advice?*** As a beginner, i will accept any **constructive** remarks/criticism.

#### Code:

```c
float conso(char posteVoulu, char poste[], int nbElem, int tableau[])
{
   int i ;
   float somme = 0.0;
   for(i = 0; i < nbElem; i++)
       {
           if (poste[i] == posteVoulu)
               {
                   somme += tableau[i];
               }
       }
   return somme / nbElem;
}


void afficher(int age[], int nbCafe[], char poste[], int nbPers)
{
   int i;

   printf("Contenu des 3 tableaux:\n\n");
   printf("  Indice  Age    #Cafe     Poste\n");
   for ( i = 0; i < nbPers; i++)
   {
       printf("%5d%8d %6d   ", i, age[i], nbCafe[i]);
       switch (poste[i])
       {
       case 'A' :
           printf("  Analyste\n");
           break;
       case 'P' :
           printf("  Programmeur\n");
           break;
       case 'O' :
           printf("  Operateur\n");
           break;
       }
   }
   printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
   char poste[] = {'A', 'P', 'O', 'P', 'A', 'O', 'P', 'P'};
   int age[]= {25, 18, 23, 20, 49, 24, 56, 29},
       nbCafe[] = {3, 1, 6, 1, 4, 1, 0, 3} ;
   int nbPers = sizeof(age) / sizeof(int);

afficher(age, nbCafe, poste, nbPers);

printf("La consomation moyenne de cafe des programmeurs : %.2f\n",
       conso('P', poste, nbPers, nbCafe));

   printf("\n");
   system("pause") ;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your new code, you are dividing the coffee consumed by programmers (5) by ALL people (8).  In your original code, you first counted the number of programmers (4).  Here's a fixed up version of `conso`:

```
float conso(char posteVoulu, char poste[], int nbElem, int tableau[])
{
   int   i;
   float somme  = 0.0;
   int   nbPers = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < nbElem; i++)
       {
           if (poste[i] == posteVoulu)
               {
                   somme += tableau[i];
                   nbPers++;
               }
       }
   if (nbPers == 0)
       return 0;
   return somme / nbPers;
}
```